# Mi aplicacion no encuentra esta ruta

Tags: laravel, npm

Tengo dos errores:

1. No encuentra la ruta
2. $ no está definido

Primero podrían ayudarme a resolver el problema de ruta. He revisado en otros proyectos y la ruta tampoco existe.

*El primer error:*

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../../node_modules/acorn/bootstrap"
    at webpackMissingModule (app.js:10515)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:10515)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:10494)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
```

*El segundo error:*

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at 265-252:2884
```

Comment: Podrias empezar por poner tu codigo, para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0):

ya solucione el problemita, tenia que editar el archivo resources/asset/js/app.js
, llamar al archivo boostrap.js correcto.

mal llamado:
require('../../../node_modules/acorn/bootstrap');
correcto:
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');

por algun motivo al pasar de version no se actualizo estos archivos.